# Tower of Galois extension with some Properties.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Give an example of a tower of Field extension $\Bbb{Q}\subset F_1\subset F_2\subset F_3$ where $F_1/\Bbb{Q}$ and $F_3/\Bbb{Q} $ are Galois
extensions but $F_2/\Bbb{Q}$ is not a Galois extension. Prove your assertion.?
My attempt:
$F_1=\Bbb{Q}$, $F_2=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ and $F_3=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3},\zeta_3)$.

$F_2/\Bbb{Q}$ is not a Galois extension because it is not normal, $F_1/\Bbb{Q}$ and $F_3/\Bbb{Q} $ are Galois because any degree one extension is Galois and $F_3$ is splitting field of $x^3+2$?

Give your answers and also why did you thought of that answer?

Comment: Does your source insist that $\subset$ means *a proper subset*? Conventions vary here. And this is kinda essential as in your example of $F_1=\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: If you want proper extensions at all the steps here is a hint: $D_4$ - the group of symmetries of a square.

Comment: Also, please take a look at my edit. For more uniform style we often include all the symbols inside dollar-signs.

Comment: I could not follow your hint

Comment: What do you know about subgroups of $D_4$? Which of them are normal, which are not? Also, you didn't comment on the meaning of $\subset$. Whether you need my hint depends on that meaning.

Comment: $\subset$ means just subset need not be proper

Comment: Ok. But, then your example is already good, right?

Comment: What I had in mind with $D_4\le S_4$ is the following. Assume $D_4$ is generated by $r=(1234)$ and $s=(13)$. Let $N$ be the subgroup generated by $s$ and $rsr^{-1}=(24)$, and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $s$ Then $N\unlhd D_4$, but $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $D_4$. So if $F_3/\Bbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension with Galois group isomorphic to $D_4$, then $F_2=\operatorname{Inv}(H)$ and $F_1=\operatorname{Inv}(N)$ behave as prescribed. For example, the splitting field of $x^4-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ has Galois group $D_4$ (has been handled on our site, me thinks).